# Forcing automatic parentheses in ipython loses tab completion

Tags: ipython, usability, parentheses, tab-completion

In `ipython` (version `0.8.1` on `Ubuntu 8.04`, version `1.1.0` on `Ubuntu 12.04`) when forcing automatic parentheses by starting the function name with <kbd>/</kbd> will make useless the <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion.

E.g.

> `In[0]:/my_ex`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
>
> `In[0]:/my_extremely_long_function_with_no_args`
>
> `-----> my_extremely_long_function_with_no_args()`

Is there a setting for keeping the tab completion?

Comment: What version of iPython are you using? This sounds like a bug, because it works fine on 1.1.0 (stable) on OSX Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `1.1.0`:

`In[0]:/`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> `my_ex`<kbd>TAB</kbd>

`-----> my_extremely_long_function_with_no_args()`

Entering <kbd>SPACE</kbd> after <kbd>/</kbd> will work on a release after `0.8.4`. `0.13.0` has it fixed. I cannot pinpoint the exact version it was introduced.

Still my expectation is not fulfilled (i.e. working without the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in between)